# Which voices can be used

Tags: youtube, google-text-to-speech

I am planning to use Google text to speech for voice over in Youtube monetized video.
I need to know which voices groups can be used for commercial purposes- Youtube monetarization.
Please provide guidance and direct me to a right group of voices